# How can I create a finite calling population model?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to simulate a finite calling population model in AnyLogic. My population consists of 10 agents and I want them to come back to the Source node after they have been served.

I thought about making conditioning with the SelectOutput node but the Source node does not have any input. The best thing that I came up with is to just limit the number of customers arrivals to 10. However, in this case, the model stops running after 10 arrivals which is not an appropriate result.

What can I do to be able to simulate such a type of model in AnyLogic?

EDIT: I thought that making agents come back to the Source node could be a solution to building the finite calling population model. The main purpose of my question is to understand how can I build such type of model in AnyLogic. Here is the [description](https://flylib.com/books/en/3.287.1.176/1/) of the concept of the model.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "come back to source node". The logic "Source" block or the visual representation of the arrival area? The former is impossible (and makes no sense), the latter can be done by simply using a "Move to" block and send your agents to the same area that they arrived in. Add some screenshots to clarify, ideally

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Benjamin! Yes, I meant the logic "Source" block. What do you mean by the visual representation of the arrival area? How can I use a "Move to" block and send my agents to the same area that they arrived in?

Comment: Please ask new questions separately, check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send them back to a Source element, as it only acts to create agents.

However, you can send them back to blocks that come after the source as below:
[image]

Here, all agents created by the Source block will infinitely loop through the Queue and Delay blocks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Maybe I have added unclarity to the question when asked about the agents coming back to the "Source" node. I am interested in how to build a finite calling population model in AnyLogic. The model is described at this link https://flylib.com/books/en/3.287.1.176/1/ .

Comment: Hi @MykolaLazarenko, happy to help but please put proper effort into your question. If you need such a model, briefly explain what it is, instead of sharing a link. I have no time to study this but happy to help on very specific questions. Please check this guide to asking good AnyLogic questions here:  https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for sharing the guide, @Benjamin!